# VB.net Decimal value of Binair checkbox

Tags: vb.net, checkbox, binary, decimal, counter

I have 8 checkboxes in a group and I want to have the decimal value for binair basicly if

checkbox1.checked = true
checkbox2.checked = true

then the value has to be (2 ^ 0) + (2 ^ 1) = 3 (the 0 = checkbox1 and the 1 = checkbox2 etc.)

I know the solution could be simple but until now I just can't get it working. The code I have right now is the following:

```
    Private Function AnyOptionsChecked() As Boolean
    For Each chk As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
        t = t + 1
        If chk.Checked = True Then
            i = i + 2 ^ t
        End If
    Next
    Return False
End Function
```

but it seems like t is already at 7 (cause there are 8 checkboxes) before the if/else starts working.

Does someone knows how to solve this problem or is able to point me in the right direction?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is returning a boolean (true/false), but really you want to be returning a number if you want to know what options have been checked. How about this:

```
Private Function OptionsChecked() As Integer
    Dim t As Integer = 0
    Dim result As Integer = 0
    For Each chk As CheckBox In GroupBox1.Controls
        If chk.Checked = True Then
            result = result + 2 ^ t
        End If
        t = t + 1
    Next
    Return result
End Function
```

So my function returns zero when no options are checked. Otherwise it returns an integer indicating which options have been checked (1 = the first option, 2 = second option, 3 = the first and second option, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the right answer. Somehow it works a bit different then I expected though. If you only select CheckBox1 it starts at 128 while you would expect CheckBox1 to start at 1. All I gotta do is turn around the checkboxes in the form which isn't that much of a problem but it still leaves me a bit confused haha! Thanks a lot for you answer it is working like a charm!

Comment: Just because you're calling it checkbox1, doesn't mean it's the first item in the collection. So it's not very robust in that sense. The addition of another checkbox to the form might completely change the ordering of the checkboxes in the collection, and hence the result of the function. So it's usefulness as a solution depends what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Right. Thanks again for the great reply. Will keep that in mind for the future!